# Moving file flat-nodes.bin from an osm2pgsql import

Tags: postgis, postgresql, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

I'm running PostgreSQL 9.4 and osm2pgsql 0.82.0 on Ubunt 14.04 (64bit).

I'm new-ish to postgres and less new to OSM. My goal was to import the planet file.

Unfortunately, when I started the import, I made the rookie mistake of not starting the osm2pgsql command from a sensible point in the filesystem.

Since I imported the planet file with the --flat-nodes option, the result (of course!) is that the flat-nodes.bin file is located in the folder I launched the command from e.g. /home/foo/bar.

I would really like to correct this and move flat-nodes.bin to a better location.

Is there a way to change where Postgres looks for the file?  I would really rather not reimport the planet.

Answer (score 1):

The flat nodes file is used directly by osm2pgsql, not by PostgreSQL. To change the location, you just have to stop automatic updates, move the flat nodes file, and change the osm2pgsql command line being called to use the new location.

If you are not updating your database, you do not need the flat nodes file at all, as it is only used by osm2pgsql.